# PHP Issue (making something free)

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a small problem making a file "Free", as in it does not count towards a member on of my site. The row in the database is called "free". I basically want this code to check the database to see if a file is free. If it is to give a slightly different result to something that ISNT free (basically saying the file is free instead of it isn't).

I have no idea where i am going wrong, but right now it's jumping past the else statement and only using the code after.

The SQL Structure is:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `torrents` (
       `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `info_hash` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT       NULL DEFAULT '',
       `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `save_as` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `search_text` text NOT NULL,
       `descr` text NOT NULL,
       `ori_descr` text NOT NULL,
       `category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `hits` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `times_completed` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `leechers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `seeders` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `last_action` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
       `visible` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
       `banned` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
       `owner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `countstats` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
       `free` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'no',
       `req` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `reseed` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT 'no',
       `last_reseed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `picone` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `pictwo` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `picthree` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
       `anonymous` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
       UNIQUE KEY `info_hash` (`info_hash`),
       KEY `owner` (`owner`),
       KEY `visible` (`visible`),
       KEY `category_visible` (`category`,`visible`),
       KEY `leechers` (`leechers`,`seeders`),
       KEY `leechers_2` (`leechers`,`seeders`),
       KEY `completed_by` (`completed_by`),
       FULLTEXT KEY `ft_search` (`search_text`,`ori_descr`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=144427 ;










    $downl = ($CURUSER["downloaded"] + $row["size"]);
      $sr = $CURUSER["uploaded"] / $downl;
    switch (true)
    {
case ($sr >= 4):
    $s = "w00t";
    break;
case ($sr >= 2):
    $s = "grin";
    break;
case ($sr >= 1):
    $s = "smile1";
    break;
case ($sr >= 0.5):
    $s = "noexpression";
    break;
case ($sr >= 0.25):
    $s = "sad";
    break;
    case ($sr > 0.00):
    $s = "cry";
    break;
default;
    $s = "w00t";
    break;
    }

      $sr = floor($sr * 1000) / 1000;
        $sr = "<font color='".get_ratio_color($sr)."'>".number_format($sr, 3).
    "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=\"pic/smilies/{$s}.gif\" alt='' />";

    if ($row['free'] == 'yes')
        {
    ?>
    <tr><td align='right' class='heading'>Ratio After Download</td><td><del><?php echo $sr;?>       

    Your new ratio if you download this torrent.</del> <b><font size="" color="#FF0000">[FREE]</font></b>
     (only upload stats are recorded)</td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <tr><td align='right' class='heading'></td><td>
    <b><font color="#FFFF00">Your ratio if you download this torrent wil be: </font></b><?php echo $sr;?> <?=$uped?></td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you also post the sql and such. We need to see the whole code to get an idea. Also try echoing out your whole table in the if/else instead of switching back and forth. Doesn't look like an error but might as well make it as simple as possible until you get it figured out.

Comment: Updated the original post :)

Comment: The code works, it just won't recognise the original statement even though it's true and jumps straight to the else statement.

Comment: Are you sure that `free` is being returned from your MySQL query?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is, as if a file is free it shows an image file to indicate it on the same page. This is the add further text information on the same page for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it might be an issues comparing strings. Try using double quotes in your if statement:

```
if ($row['free'] == "yes")
```

PHP is less strict with double quotes that could possibly help.

If that doesn't work try using a column that stores a boolean (true,false) instead of a string as it is much easier to test a boolean than a string so it would be

```
if ($row['free'] == true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've tried both and it still jumps to the second statement after the else, even though the file is set as  yes (in the database) (and should give the first statement).

Comment: can you add your "select" sql/php, I see where you create the table but not where you pull anything into php. Your default is "no" for 'free' can you echo out the row just to double check it is returning 'yes'?

edited for grammer

Comment: You were right, i was missing a call query to the database for the "free". Thank you! Right answer. Good job! :)